# Remote ray call Ignoring function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, ray

I am trying to apply `ray` to a transformer pipeline as:

```
@ray.remote
def predict(pipeline, text_data, max_length, min_length, do_sample):
    return pipeline(text_data, max_length, min_length, do_sample)
```

and initializing as:

```
predictions = ray.get(predict.remote(pipe_1, section, max_length=some_length, min_length=some_length, do_sample=False))
```

the pipeline `pipe_1` is defined using `ray.put()`

```
pipe_1 = ray.put("transformer pipeline method definition")
```

Pipeline method definition is similar to as described [here](https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-cnn). I have initialized `ray.init()` as :
`ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus, ignore_reinit_error=True)`

However its seems my `*args` are being ignored. Looks like `max_length`, `min_length` and `do_sample` arguments are ignored - below is the sample console output:

```
(predict pid=19440) Ignoring args : (529, 423, False)
(predict pid=19440) Ignoring args : (680, 544, False)
```

Any suggestions.

Source code and article: [Parallel Inference of HuggingFace  Transformers on CPUs](https://towardsdatascience.com/parallel-inference-of-huggingface-transformers-on-cpus-4487c28abe23)

Comment: Can you provide me a self-runnable script?

Answer (score 0):

Copy-pasting from [discuss](https://discuss.ray.io/t/remote-ray-call-ignoring-function-arguments/7413):

Sorry I’m not exactly sure what you mean by the args getting ignored. Could you post a runnable reproduction, preferably without the actual pipeline (you can just use an empty function)?

I’m not sure if this is related to your issue, but I would also suggest calling pipeline as a remote function instead of passing it into the wrapper task. This is likely to be more efficient and fault-tolerant, as Ray will broadcast the pipeline definition to all workers beforehand. You can do this like so:

```py
pipe1 = "transformer pipeline method definition"
pipe1_remote_fn = ray.remote(pipe1)
pipe1_remote_fn.remote(section, max_length=some_length, min_length=some_length, do_s
```